# Corollary of Weyl's Theorem - direct sum of simple ideals

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, ideals, direct-sum

Weyl's Theorem states that if $L$ is a semisimple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, then any finite dimensional representation of $L$ is completely reducible.

I want to show that a corollary of this is that if $L$ is a semisimple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, then we are able to decompose $L$ into a direct sum of simple ideals, say $L=L_1\oplus \dots \oplus L_s$, where $L_i$ are simple ideals.

Weyls' Theorem tells us that if we have $(\rho, V)$ as a (finite dimensional) representation for $L$, then we can write $V=V_1 \oplus \dots \oplus V_r$, a direct sum of irreducible subrepresentations, where each $V_i$ is $L$ - stable.

I'm not sure where to proceed from here, I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Consider the adjoint representation. Subrepresentations are just ideals.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you!